# How to identify an object and make a relationship among them [c#]

Tags: oop

What is the best way to identify the objects and their Relationship between them ?
As i am new to Programming[c# windows application],I am finding difficult in making relationship between objects .
Can anyone suggest me the best way to start with?

Thanks,
Karthik

Comment: You are not "new to C# windows applications", you need a programming for beginners book.

Comment: What do you mean , your question is quite vague

Comment: It would be much easier for us to help you if you gave us some idea of what your application needs to do. We can then at least give you some basic examples to get started.

Answer (score 4):

You should probably read up on object oriented programming and design. Then read up on C# programming.

Here are a few book suggestions:

- [Head First Object Oriented Analysis and Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596008678)
- [Beginning C# 3.0: An Introduction to Object Oriented Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470261293)

Then when you're ready, you can move on to [Jon Skeet's book](http://www.manning.com/skeet2/) =)

If you're not looking to purchase a book, maybe take a look at this [site](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrinciplesOfObjectOrientedDesign). It covers key object oriented design principles.

Answer (score 2):

I'll try and point you in the right direction with a contrived example:

*Suppose we want to make a simple management application for supermarket staff. We are required to store some personal information and work-related information, so we'll need name, address, date started, department, and position.*

So now we can try and summarise this specification and think about how to model each bit of data.

1. StaffMember

   - Name
   - Address
   - Date Started
   - Department
2. Department

   - Name
   - Position
3. Position

   - Title
   - Roles

Now we can map these ideas to `c# classes` and use `properties` to hold the bits of data we need:

```
class StaffMember
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateStarted { get; set; }
    public Department Department { get; set; }    // class Department
}

class Department
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Position Position { get; set; }    // class Position
}

class Position
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string PrimaryRole { get; set; }
}
```

Sample usage:

```
static void Main()
{
    StaffMember employee = new StaffMember();
    employee.Name = "Ali Gray";
    employee.Address = "123 Abc Street";
    employee.DateStarted = DateTime.Now;

    // Now add the employees department
    employee.Department = new Department();
    employee.Department.Name = "Checkout";

    // Now add the employees position
    employee.Department.Position = new Position();
    employee.Department.Position.Title = "Bag Packer";
    employee.Department.Position.PrimaryRole = "Pack bags";
}
```

Obviously this is an extremely simplified example, but hopefully it'll help you on your way to understanding `oo design`.